# Anything needed beside .NET framework to run a native powershell script on a server?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I have written a PS script and I want to run the PS script on set of servers (Windows servers 2008/2003). However, I have been told that, in Addition to the .Net framework, the servers needs some PowerShell-specific files and configuration to be able to run the script.

**Please consider the following**:

-Only native api was used in the script with no module or extrnal library reference: Get-Date, Get-ChildItem, Get-Service, Get-Content, [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($XYZ) .. etc

-Do I need to install [Windows Management Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930) on each and every server in order to run PowerShell?

-What if the PS script was called from a C# Console application? Anything will be needed beside the .Net frame work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is ebabled by default on Windows server 2008 R2, on 2008 PowerShell v1 is a feature to be enabled and v2 is a download.  On 2003 both v1 and v2 are a separate download.

It doesn't matter what calls the script it will still be executed by PowerShell.

Comment: Ok.... So assuming PS is enabled, do i need anything beside .net framework to run a powershell script?

Comment: Depends on what the script references and uses internally.

Comment: I am only using native PS api with no module or extrnal library refrence. I have also updated my question with this info.

Comment: In that case there are no other depedencies.